# install python google cloud storage client on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu, google-cloud-storage

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04, 32 bit. I am getting this error in my Google App Engine server code:

> ```
> import cloudstorage
> ```
>
> ImportError: No module named cloudstorage

I ran this command to install the GCS module:

> pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t /home/john/software/google_appengine/lib/ --force-reinstall

My coworker installed the cloudstorage module on Windows 7 by simply copying the 'cloudstorage' folder to the GAE/lib folder. Running the code on his PC does not produce  ImportError. I also tried this

How can I install the cloudstorage module on Linux to avoid the ImportError?

Comment: what version of python are you trying to install it for?

Comment: try https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/#install

Comment: @PadraicCunningham
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'

Comment: @Ashish I am having this same problem. Could you explain why are you suggesting installing Google Compute Engine? I don't want spurious files on my disk, in many cases without knowing how to delete them if it turns out they have nothing to do with solving the problem. So could you please explain what gcutil has to do with `import cloudstorage` producing the error message "No module named cloudstorage"? Thanks. (By the way, gcutil is deprecated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install the client, using svn you get the demos and test code:

Download:   `svn checkout http://appengine-gcs-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python gcs-client`

Then `cd gcs-client/src` and `sudo/python or python setup.py install`

You can use  pip  but you won't get the demos and test code:

```
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <your_app_directory/lib>
```

Comment: "you_app_directory/lib" was really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I tried using "pip" first. I wasn't sure what you meant by <your_app_directory> so I installed it without the "-t" option, and then with "-t" specifying the lib under my application, and finally in the lib where GAE is installed in my Applications directory. After each "pip" command (two of them needed "sudo pip"), I tried my app and still got "No module named cloudstorage" on my `import cloudstorage as gcs` statement. I then tried using the "svn", "cd" and "sudo python" (without the slash) commands you gave. I'm still getting "No module named cloudstorage".

Answer (score 5):

The library needs to be installed in your application directory. Docs suggest using PIP to put it in `<app>/lib`::

```
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <your_app_directory/lib>
```

What they don't mention is that if you have to create a `lib` directory, you need to put an (empty) `__init__.py` in `lib` so that Python reads it as importable. You'll also need to say `import lib.cloudstorage`.

Comment: Great way to communicate the answer. BTW, I avoided the "lib." prefix when importing by extending the python search path. I also did not need the empty [code]__init__.py[/code] file (at least with devserver).

Comment: I don't want to create a lib folder inside my app directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <app_root>
```

Then test if it works with:

```
python -c "import cloudstorage"
```