# Google Cloud and Appengine Python Package conflict

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-python, gcloud-python

I'm going through google's appengine tutorials and made the [simple example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/python-standard-env) of posting a form ans retrieving the information. Through the tutorial steps I had to install Google Cloud SDK with the appengine libs.

It works fine.

One step forward I pip installed "[google-cloud](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud)" package, to retrieve a file from Google Storage.

After installed both google cloud packages,when trying a simple import from my `main.py` file as:

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named google.cloud.storage
```

Printing `google.__path__` I can see the correct path to both packages:

```
[
'/home/xpto/.virtualenvs/dev01/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google',
'/home/xpto/.virtualenvs/dev01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google', 
'/home/xpto/Software/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google', 
'/home/xpto/projects/testProject01/lib/google'
]
```

What am I missing here?

Running python from the terminal in the same virtualenv I can import google.clou packages without problem. The error message appears only when I run it using `dev_appserver.py`

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of [Python on Google Cloud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100031/install-python-google-cloud-storage-client-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399303/using-two-python-libraries-with-conflicting-names

Comment: Dan Cornilescu, I think it is something like this, but I already have the appengine_config.py identical to the proposed solution. Have any other ideas? I added more info to the question.

Comment: Not really, I managed to stick with the GAE SDK so far, didn't switch to the cloud SDK yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk.  But that's not what's being recommended these days, tho... Monitoring related threads, tho - I know I have to switch eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I installed Google Cloud SDK using the [Linux tar.gz](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#linux) package instead of the [Debian/Ubuntu installation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb) procedure.

Somehow the tar.gz package messed up my python path. Creating a new environment solved.

Answer (score 3):

Dan Cornilescu linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399303/using-two-python-libraries-with-conflicting-names) which looks it might work.

If that doesn't work, you can usually hack import paths to fix it. I usually don't add the app engine SDK to my virtualenv at all and then just add it manually:

```
import google

google.__path__.append('/path/to/appengine_sdk//google_appengine/google')
sys.path.insert(0, gae_dir) # might not be necessary

import google.appengine # now it's on your import path`
```

Leave a comment if none of these approaches work.

Comment: Hi Bill, the path to both packages are already listed in the google.__path__ . I added more info to the question. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes mine is identical to the one proposed in Dan Cornilescu link.

Comment: @Maviles, sorry you have me a bit stumped, maybe if you can repro it on a simple Github repo I can take a look?

Comment: Hi Bill, I put it on github repo https://github.com/mhaa/gclouderror much appreciate the help. thanks

Comment: Your code sample runs fine on dev_appserver.py for me with no import errors. On gcloud 139.0.1. Are you by chance messing with your PYTHONPATH environment variable before running dev_appserver.py?

Comment: Thanks @Adam, As it worked for you and I couldn't find out the error, the only way was to start a whole new enviroment. Now it is working. So it was probably a configuration error.